# Как правильно работать с указателями void

Tags: c, функции, void

подскажите как правильно работать с указателями на функцию void при передаче этого указателя в качестве аргумента в другую функцию.
Имеются около 10 функций вида:

```
void func_xx (void)
```

они используются для вывода текста LCD на дисплей, напрямую из `main` не вызываются.
Их я хочу ввести в качестве аргумента в более сложную функцию, вызываемую из `main`

```
void parametr_edit (int8 x, int16 y, <тут должен быть указатель на void func_xx (void)> )
```

с точки зрения ассемблера, в коде функции `parametr_edit` должен быть обычный вызов одной из функций `func_xx`. Попробовал поискать в интернете, но в основном попадается указатель на не `void`. За 3 года работы впервые сталкнулся с указателями на функции, да ито потому, что потребовалось освободить немного места в ПЗУ МК. Решаем ли такой вопрос, и с чего начинать?

Comment: "на функцию void " - у вас ничего подобного нет. "Попробовал поискать в интернете" - Такие заявления могут выглядеть правдоподобно, если были приведены какие-то конкретные результаты таких поисков и что с ними не так.

Answer (score 1):

Просто

```
void (*)(void)
```

См., например, https://ideone.com/00Zskj

Только уверен — ничего вы [в Интернете](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E%20%D0%B2%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E%20%D0%A1) не искали...

Comment: Спасибо, когда подряд попадались указатели только на int взяло сомнение, попробую...

Answer (score -1):

Как только что выяснилось, на Гарвардской платформе устройства, не действуют обычные правила установленные для С работающего с платформой единого пространства адресации.
Здесь приходится подшаманить при работе с указателями на функции размещенных в ПЗУ (для указателей на данные в ОЗУ все работает прекрасно)
пример

```
typedef void (*PTR)();

void func()
{
printf("Hello World\n\r");
}

void call(PTR argument)
{
argument();
}
```

при вызовах в `main`

```
call(func);
```

без этого к сожаленью не заработало

Comment: Не вижу никакой разницыс моим кодом — кроме использования `typedef`...

Comment: Согласен, я сам целый день провозился пытаясь разобраться почему не работает, но тем не менее без этого у меня не работает